# Persistent Header Issue (JQuery & CSS3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little question, I made a persistent header with a CSS3 animation which fully works. But after I scrolled down, the content just disappears. I hope you guys get me, because I don't know another way to explain this.

This is my HTML code:

```
<section id="container" class="container">
    <header>
        <section class="inner">
            <section class="row">
                <section class="five columns"><!--LOGO SPOT-->
                        LOGO
                </section><!--//LOGO SPOT-->
                <section class="seven columns"><!--MENU SPOT-->
                    <nav>
                        <li><a href='#'>Homepage</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
                    </nav>
                </section><!--//MENU SPOT-->
            </section>
        </section>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="row content">
            <section class="twelve columns jumbotron">
                asd
            </section>
            <section class="inner">
                <section class="row">
                    <section class="three columns">
                        Feature #1
                    </section>
                    <section class="three columns">
                        Feature #2
                    </section>
                    <section class="three columns">
                        Feature #3
                    </section>
                    <section class="three columns">
                        Feature #4
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</section>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php SYS_PATH; ?>js/header.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
header {
height: 85px;
background: #335C7D;
width: 100%;

-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

header.sticky {
position: fixed;
height: 48px; 
background: #efc47D;
}
```

This is my JQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
} else {
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
}
});
```

So what happens with the scrolling?
Before: http://prntscr.com/76payg
After: http://prntscr.com/76pb5j

As you can see to the scrolling bar, I just scrolled a litle millimetre orso.

I hope someone can help me out, thank you.

Comment: Can you provide css for main? Is it possible the content is behind your header? When you set position to fixed, it removes it from the flow of the page. So your main will go up 85px. From your screenshot it looks low enough, but  still, it could be part of the problem.

Comment: @JulienGrégoire The only CSS rule in main is: 
height: 200px;

Comment: Just for testing, try to set top: 100px for example. Again, it's hard without seeing the actual page, but switching header to fixed without correcting your main will most likely mess up your layout.

Comment: @JulienGrégoire I think I found the problem. As soon as I scroll down, the header gets smaller and the text what you see, the: Feature #1 etc gets placed under the header.